# UIManager errors on startup in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Every time I start latest JMeter 5 GUI with plugins on windows 7 I get 2 errors on log:

```
ERROR e.l.j.w.GuiUtils: UIManager does not support color key 'Label.disabledForeground'
```

I open a issue for [RSyntaxTextArea](https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea/issues/304), which says it's irrelevant error from their library

> This doesn't appear to be related to RSTA. GuiUtils is not a class in this library.

How can I overcome these errors? It doesn't happens with JMeter 4 with plugins

**EDIT**

It happens only when adding `WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch` plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happens only when adding WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch plugin,

I Created an [Issue #120](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/120/error-uimanager-does-not-support-color-key)

> ERROR UIManager does not support color key 'Label.disabledForeground'